# When starting an Azure Function, don't auto-start the emulator, etc

Tags: visual-studio, azure, azure-functions

I'm experimenting with Azure Functions (v3/latest at the time of this post).

When I hit F5 to run/debug the app, Microsoft Storage Emulator auto starts/kicks in. I prefer to use (the newer, superseding) Azurite as my emulator.

Is there a setting that can tell Visual Studio, that when I click F5, don't auto-start the Microsoft Storage Emulator ?

UPDATE:

This is not a question about connection strings. This is only about telling Visual Studio to -not- try and start the Microsoft Azure emulator.

Comment: `The AzureWebJobsStorage` in the `Values` section in the `local.settings.json` of Azure Function determines the storage emulator. Can you get Azurite's connection string? If you can, you can try to provide it to `AzureWebJobsStorage`,

Comment: Not sure if Azurite can be used as an emulator. You can have a try.

Comment: @BowmanZhu - I think you misunderstood the question. I know how to use Azurite as the emulator. This is not about connection strings. This is about how Visual Studio tries to auto-start it's own Storage Emulator ... which I do not want it to do.

Comment: then use a real storage account, your issue isnt making much sense

Comment: @AlexGordon thanks for comment. OK - so how does Visual Studio not try and start the local emulator if I use a connection string to a real storage account in azure?

Answer (score 4):

To prevent the Azure Storage Emulator from starting automatically, just add the property `<StartDevelopmentStorage>False</StartDevelopmentStorage>` to your .csproj.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As per Alex mentioned, if you don't want to auto-start local emulator, you should use the real connection string in `local.settings.json`. Like below:

```
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
    "Values": {
        "AzureWebJobsStorage": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=xxx;AccountKey=xxxx;BlobEndpoint=https://xxx.blob.core.windows.net/;TableEndpoint=https://xxx.table.core.windows.net/;QueueEndpoint=https://xxx.queue.core.windows.net/;FileEndpoint=https://xxx.file.core.windows.net/",
        "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet"
    }
}
```

Since you're now using the real connection string, Visual studio will not use local emulator. Thus it will not be started at all.

Btw, I've already tested it(function v3 with latest nuget packages), local emulator behaves like I said.

Comment: So visual studio has some code that checks the connection string? and if it's `UseDevelopmentStorage=true` (for any key/value) then it will auto start the emulator?

Comment: @Pure.Krome, I think so as per the behavior. But I cannot find any docs which explicitly clarify that.

Comment: @Pure.Krome Hello, if the answer is helpful, could you please accept it as answer? Thanks.